# Prevent a pause in animation with config using a react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I'm trying to make a spring effect animation using a `react-spring` library and I have reached the animating what I need but there is one problem:
When I'm passing a custom config with: `mass`, `tension`, `friction` I'm getting a nice "jumping" effect but it should animate it on the full width from `50px` to `100px` but instead of this, it's making a sth like a "pause" effect when it reaches the `100px` position, e.g.:

1. Starting animation by changing `width` from `50px` to `100px` and making a spring effect.
2. Pause
3. Ending animation by changing `width` from `100px` to `50px` and making a spring effect.

This is how looks like my code:

```
const Line = () => {
  const props = useSpring({
    from: { width: "50px", height: "10px" },
    to: [
      { width: "100px", height: "5px" },
      { width: "50px", height: "10px" }
    ],
    config: {
      mass: 0.3,
      tension: 122,
      friction: 2.5
    }
  });
  return <animated.div className="line" style={props} />;
};

function App() {
  const [on, set] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Line key={on} />
        <div className="box" />
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => set(!on)}>Trigger</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here you can find a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-demo-44hjjz

Am I missing something in my code? Or maybe I should change something?